# Is there a way to load translations from .PO and .MO files for Customizer strings?

Tags: theme-customizer, translation

I would like to ask if there is a way, a filter or a hook that lets us display the translated strings of the Customizer options.

For example, most WordPress themes provide translation files in the theme (that are in the languages folder) so if we switch the language of WordPress to let's say Spanish and if the files are present for Spanish then the strings appear just fine.

However, we still have to translate the strings or labels that are only found and controlled in Customizer settings. So, I want to find a way to load the strings from the translation files (if present) for the Customizer settings (that matches the string in the translation files).

Thanks

Comment: Hmm....Customizer controls have text labels as any other fields' labels. If they are not used with `__()` (or other translation functions), just add them by yourself. Than you will be able to update your .po/.mo files with these strings.

Comment: I don't know why these strings would be different from any others. Can you share what you currently have?

Comment: Actually, I am finding a way to pre-define the translation using the language files which I generate using POEdit. However, those language files are unaffected for the Customizer strings.